# GDAL - Unable to open PDF or SVG

Tags: qgis, gdal

I'm trying to import a PDF of a floor plan of a school into QGIS. I was able to open this PDF  in QGIS georeferencer and it recognized points, lines, and polygons and I was able to georeference these. However, I am unable to open page 2 of the PDF in QGIS, even though it is still vectorized. Page 2 of the original floor plan PDF contains the basement, floor two, and floor three of the building. Page 1 contained the first floor of the building. I have opened up this pdf in Adobe Illustrator and selected the vectors and exported the data from page two into separate files, in both PDF and SVG format. I can open these files in web browsers, verifying that AI exported valid files.

Using `gdalinfo` on the original pdf works, it gives me the following information:

```
C:\OSGeo4W>gdalinfo "C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\NCHS Map.pdf"
Driver: PDF/Geospatial PDF
Files: C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\NCHS Map.pdf
       C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\NCHS Map.pdf.aux.xml
Size is 1650, 1275
Metadata:
  AUTHOR=paquino
  CREATION_DATE=D:20110523132940-05'00'
  CREATOR=Adobe Illustrator CS3
  PRODUCER=Bluebeam PDF Library 6.5.1
Subdatasets:
  SUBDATASET_1_NAME=PDF:1:C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\NCHS Map.pdf
  SUBDATASET_1_DESC=Page 1 of C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\NCHS Map.pdf
  SUBDATASET_2_NAME=PDF:2:C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\NCHS Map.pdf
  SUBDATASET_2_DESC=Page 2 of C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\NCHS Map.pdf
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0, 1275.0)
Upper Right ( 1650.0,    0.0)
Lower Right ( 1650.0, 1275.0)
Center      (  825.0,  637.5)
Band 1 Block=1650x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Min=7.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=7.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=210.985, StdDev=83.382
  Overviews: 825x637, 412x319, 206x159
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=210.98494840325
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=7
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=83.382192841337
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 2 Block=1650x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Min=7.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=7.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=210.381, StdDev=84.068
  Overviews: 825x637, 412x319, 206x159
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=210.3808389815
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=7
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=84.06814604047
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 3 Block=1650x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Min=6.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=6.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=210.102, StdDev=84.646
  Overviews: 825x637, 412x319, 206x159
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_APPROXIMATE=YES
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=210.10212493131
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=6
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=84.645715871308
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Using `gdalinfo` on the exported pdf of the third floor gives me this, however:

```
Driver: PDF/Geospatial PDF
Files: C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\PDF\Asset 1.pdf
       C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\PDF\Asset 1.pdf.aux.xml
Size is 770, 538
Metadata:
  CREATION_DATE=D:20240213141116-05'00'
  CREATOR=Adobe Illustrator 26.3 (Windows)
  PRODUCER=Adobe PDF library 16.07
  TITLE=Asset 1
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (    0.0,    0.0)
Lower Left  (    0.0,  538.0)
Upper Right (  770.0,    0.0)
Lower Right (  770.0,  538.0)
Center      (  385.0,  269.0)
Band 1 Block=770x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=235.439, StdDev=63.042
  Overviews: 385x269, 193x134
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=235.43944382755
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=63.04246571698
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 2 Block=770x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=235.443, StdDev=63.040
  Overviews: 385x269, 193x134
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=235.44324578767
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=63.040298131887
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
Band 3 Block=770x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Min=0.000 Max=255.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=255.000, Mean=235.451, StdDev=63.036
  Overviews: 385x269, 193x134
  Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
    STATISTICS_MEAN=235.45084970791
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=63.036142992333
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100
```

Even worse, `ogrinfo` just gives up.

```
ogrinfo failed - unable to open 'C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\PDF\Asset 1.pdf'.
```

The svg file exports are the same.

```
ERROR 4: `C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\SVG\Third Floor.svg' not recognized as a supported file format.
ogrinfo failed - unable to open 'C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\SVG\Third Floor.svg'.
```

`ogr2ogr` is also useless.

```
Unable to open datasource `C:\Users\ejscamehorn1\Desktop\NCHSNav\mapping-src\PDF\Asset 1.pdf' with the following drivers.
  -> `PCIDSK'
  -> `netCDF'
  -> `PDS4'
  -> `VICAR'
  -> `JP2ECW'
  -> `JP2OpenJPEG'
  -> `PDF'
...
```

Comment: Is there any reason you are using a PDF file as opposed to a high-res JPEG? Generally QGIS works nicer with raster files.

Comment: Have you tried using a PDF editor to split out the second page, rather than Illustrator? Also interesting that you were able to import a pdf with vectorised data, Georeferencer has always compressed it into a raster for me

Comment: @wildkoala using a rasterization of the floor plan allows me to georeference it, however the quality of this is not what I'm looking for in my application. Rasterization is too low quality and I need to be able to modify vectors (like deleting numbers from rooms to create multiple varying levels of detail).

Comment: @she_weeds Unfortunately using adobe acrobat or firefox to save just the second page of the PDF to a new file doesn't work. Page 2 has 3 maps on it, which I need to further separate to then georeference.